# Swap is turned off after reboot on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, swap

Swap turned off after reboot, but it works after turning
on swap with this command

```
 sudo swapon /media/oleg/5C2C1D0A2C1CE0B6/swapfile
```

Why?

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on SSD. I have HDD with NTFS file system.
I created swap file on NTFS partition not to put it on SSD.

`/etc/fstab` looks like:

```
UUID=26a50687-bfb3-4486-b822-9884130669de /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=E055-53B9  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1

/media/oleg/5C2C1D0A2C1CE0B6/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

The computer has 8Gb, now it works ok without swap, but maybe it 
makes sense to add swap file just in case.

Comment: `/media/oleg/5C2C1D0A2C1CE0B6` isn't configured in fstab, how do you normally mount that? You can not access and enable a swap file at boot with fstab if the file system on which it is located isn't mounted using fstab too. Also, swap files on NTFS are a relatively bad idea. See e.g. https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5534

Comment: It's mounted automatically on every reboot. It's hdd, not external disk

Comment: Yeah, but *how*? It must be configured in fstab, everything else happens later. Too late for the swap file.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to configure it in fstab for ntfs partition?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, I think I could make it work and I added answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that the NTFS file system on which I placed my swap file was not configured to mount automatically in `/etc/fstab`, but it got only mounted automatically later somewhere.

I added this in `/etc/fstab`, it seems to work now:

```
/dev/sdb4 /media/oleg/5C2C1D0A2C1CE0B6 ntfs-3g rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096 0 0
```

And this line remains telling linux to use swap file after reboot.
    /media/oleg/5C2C1D0A2C1CE0B6/swapfile none swap sw 0 0

Comment: What?? I want a explanation of why it works...

Comment: Can you see any issues with this solutions?
It looks like it work.

Answer (score 2):

If all you previously had in your `fstab` file was the line mounting

```
/media/oleg/5C2C1D0A2C1CE0B6/swapfile none swap sw 0
```

the problem would have been that

> /media/oleg/xxxx was not mounted automatically.

By adding

```
/dev/sdb4 /media/oleg/5C2C1D0A2C1CE0B6 ntfs-3g rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions
```

to the `fstab`, now `/dev/sdb4` is mounted before the swap is needed.
I would move the whole thing to a different location, e.g create a folder named `/new_swap`, and then replace the two lines in the swapfile that use `/media/oleg` with:

```
/dev/sdb4 /newswap  none swap sw 0
```

So, now you would have a one-step mounting/swap creation rather than a 2step one.

Comment: or maybe the line should be "/dev/sdb4 none  swap sw 0 0"